# order by direction as a parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, prepared-statement

i want to sort my result based on parameter:

```
select ... group by some_column :paramter
```

and the `parameter` should be `asc` or `desc`. but when i try it, i get error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "$6"

is it possible in postgres? if i send the query from the server, i can just concatenate the query but what if it's inside a stored procedure? i would prefer to avoid concatenating strings to build a query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are my options for using dynamic sort field/order in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48953496/what-are-my-options-for-using-dynamic-sort-field-order-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

SQL parameters cannot be placed in that location. They are meant to apply scalar values to the SQL template, but not to modify the SQL query structure itself.

What you need is to implement "Dynamic SQL" here, but that's a different strategy.